# getting error mailx: illegal option -- a while adding attachment in bash scripting

Tags: shell, scripting, aix

```sh
echo "${MAIL_MSG}"| mailx -a "${opfile}" -s "${MAIL_SUBJ}" "${DW_EMAIL_LIST}"
```

above command throwing error mailx: illegal option -- a. Can u please help me out how to sort it out?

Comment: Please provide some extra details of your setup. For instance, what operating system, what version, etc.

Comment: connected to server using shell. 
 uname -a
op : AIX mrma70p4 1 7 00F9F76C4C00

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is `mail` not `mailx`

Example email with attachment:

```
$ echo "This is message body" | mail -s "This is Subject" -r "Harry<harry@gmail.com>" -a /path/to/file someone@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for ur input. But it's not working -same error.

Comment: echo ${MAIL_MSG} | mailx -s "${MAIL_SUBJ}" ${MAIL_LIST} 
above command is working fine but I getting an error while I am trying to add an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115334/mail-command-to-send-attachements is a similar question about sending mail with attachments on AIX.  It suggests `mime-construct`.  If that's not available, you might be able to use `mutt`.  Looking at the [mutt man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mutt), it looks like the syntax is very similar:

```
echo "${MAIL_MSG}" | mutt -x -s "${MAIL_SUBJ}" -a "${opfile}" -- "${DW_EMAIL_LIST}"
```

Here's a summary of the options:

- `-x` is mailx compatible compose mode
- `-s` is the subject
- `-a` is the attachment
- `--` separates attachments from recipients

Note that `-a` must be the last option:

> -a file [...] Attach a file to your message using MIME. When attaching single or multiple files, separating filenames and recipient addresses
>   with "--" is mandatory, e.g. mutt -a image.jpg -- addr1 or mutt -a
>   img.jpg *.png -- addr1 addr2. The -a option must be placed at the end
>   of command line options.